# Access text in dynamically generated TextView by ContextMenu

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to develop some sort of user profile in an app for android 4.0. In this activity I am adding an undefined number of fields of the following type. Now I want to add a context menu to all the fields and access the text on both fields in this pair, no matter which one was long-clicked.

```
<GridLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="1" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscriberFieldTextPrefix"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFAAAAAA"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscriberFieldTextText"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</GridLayout>
```

I am adding these "rows" by code like this:

```
view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.subscriber_field_text, null);

((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subscriberFieldTextPrefix)).setText(currentSubscriber.GetSpecialFields().get(i).GetField() + ": ");
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subscriberFieldTextText)).setText(currentSubscriber.GetSpecialFields().get(i).GetValue());

registerForContextMenu(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subscriberFieldTextPrefix)));
registerForContextMenu(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subscriberFieldTextText)));

layout.addView(view);
```

This would be my event for creating the menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "test2");
}
```

Now in this event I can get the ID of the original field which only leads me to the template in the XML. And I also get the text on the original field but I have no idea how to get both of them. The text is completely enough, I don't need the objects.

I hope somebody can help... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to assign your generated `TextView` to a class variable and extract the data from there.

```
TextView blahText = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subscriberFieldTextPrefix)).setText(currentSubscriber.GetSpecialFields().get(i).GetField() + ": ");
```

and access that `TextView` later on. The generally visible variable could also be an array of TextViews (or maybe a Map?) and that would give you even more visibility

```
List<TextView> textViewRows = new ArrayList<TextView>();
```

or

```
Map<String,TextView> mapOfRows = new HashMap<String,TextView>();
```

One way to use the Map would be by using the Menu as the Key and the View as the Value.

```
Map<MenuItem,View> mapOfTextViews = new HashMap<MenuItem,View>();
```

so that the creation of your context Menus populates them

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    MenuItem newMenu = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "test2");
    mapOfTextViews.put(newMenu,v);
}
```

When the menuItem gets clicked you use the MenuItem to look up the current View.

Comment: I am not sure if this would work as I currently have no reference at all which clicked field would be the one in my TextView Array. I there is a possibility for this I would of course also except that.

Comment: Caught me while I was amplifying my answer. Look at the changes I applied, maybe that will help you with your problem.

Comment: It is not the problem with the array/list/map or something else. I have the text available wherever I need it, it is just that I do not know which field was pressed when this event was fired. When I select v.getId() I can find out whether it was the left one or right one, but not if the first, second or last. This text is not unique, so looping through all of them to find the correct one would also not be an option.

Comment: Modified the answer again. Caveat emptor: I was unable to test it at this time, so I'm not entirely sure it will work.